# A website matching two users - confirming connect

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering mainly about how a site like this would work, i.e. a user searches for another, and when it finds the other, it provides them with information about that user. Then the websites part is done, it just needs to remove both users from the queue based on them connecting.

Any ideas on concept for this? I don't think a membership system is required since it's a one time search.

Comment: Reveals the information of each other to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data storage would get very close to being equivalent to a membership system. Both individuals would need to input the information by which they can be found through a search and this would probably then be stored in a database. When one user finds another, you could remove them both from the database, but then neither of them could be found by another user.

This really depends on your specific needs.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was more or less wondering how two users would connect with just each other, instead of user1 finding user3 while user2 finds user1. Not sure how it would halt both searches once one finds the other.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the purpose of this. Is the sole purpose only for one person to "find" another and once those two people find each other then they don't search for anyone else?